# jquery resizable from attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, attributes, resizable

i managed to resize multiple classes

```
$('.s').resizable({ alsoResize: '.1,.2,.3' });
```

but i want to get the alsoresizable objects from the attribute 
in the main object i resize. how can i get the attribute values there?

i tried:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".resizable" ).resizable({
        maxHeight: 100,
        maxWidth: 162,
        minHeight: 14,
        minWidth: 162,

        alsoResize: "."+$(this).attr('number')+" "
    });
});
</script>
```

but its not working.
can someone help?

here is a jfiddle for testing: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dichterDichter/ewRWG/47/)

Comment: Can you post a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can see what's going on elsewhere in your page/scripts?

Comment: i have posted a fiddle which shows my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could build up the list with `$.each` or maybe `$.map`:

```
$.map($('your-selector'), function (element) { 
    return '.' + $(element).attr('number'); 
}).join(',')
```

Comment: i found a way to make it working, i figured out that i have to define all options when initializing the resizable. it uses the variable which is defined at the beginning, so even if i change the variable when i click its the old one. this helps but i have to click two times: http://jsfiddle.net/dichterDichter/HQ9EY/104/

Answer (score 0):

this works:

js:

```
$(".res").mouseover(function() {
    //alert($(this).attr("number"));
    $(".res").resizable( "option", "alsoResize", $(this).attr("number") );
    });

$(".res").resizable({
    });
```

html:

```
<div id="div" class="a res ui-widget ui-widget-content" number=".b">Test A</div>
<div id="div" class="b res ui-widget ui-widget-content" number=".c">Test B</div>
<div id="div" class="c res ui-widget ui-widget-content" number=".a,.b">Test C</div>
```